# 404 Status When Creating New App with Gracenote API

Tags: gracenote

I'm trying to create an API key to use the Gracenote Mobile SDK for an iOS app. However, when I'm logged in and on the "My Apps" page within Gracenote's Developer site, I get the following message at the bottom of the page:

STATUS: 404 - Not Found; Communication with the Apigee endpoint is compromised. Cannot get API Products List.

Any idea why this is happening / what I can do to get a key?

Answer (score 0):

That error was due to a temporary connectivity problem with the website. Service has now been restored.